# Function already created: concat. Watir webdriver, ChromeDriver 2.2, mobile user agent

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir, selenium-chromedriver

I am getting the error

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: unknown error: Function already created: concat.
(Session info: chrome=29.0.1547.62)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.2,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)
```

when running a Cucumber test via Jenkins, command-line or from RubyMine.

I am using Watir webdriver, Chromedriver 2.2, the webdriver-user-agent Gem (to set the user agent to a mobile user agent). The error occurs after getting to the PayPal sandbox site and executing:

```
assert @browser.link(:class=>"scTrack bn:payWithCard").present?
```

or:

```
assert @browser.text.include?(str)
```

I have tried asserting text exists earlier on in the test and it works fine. Maybe it has something to do with the redirect that occurs during the PayPal page:

> Please wait while we transfer you to PayPal
>
> If you have not been connected within 1 minute click here

There are no definitions for anything called concat in our code. I have 63 other tests with the same initialisation code, mobile user agent etc. and none of those throw exceptions. I doubt it matters, but I'm using Windows 7 Professional 64-bit.

Comment: The following code run in IRB console will cause the error to occur:

    require 'watir-webdriver'
    require 'webdriver-user-agent'
    driver = UserAgent.driver(:browser => :chrome, :agent => :android_phone, :orientation => :landscape)
    browser = Watir::Browser.new driver
    browser.window.resize_to(500, 900)
    browser.goto('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-82N89187TB867720T&useraction=commit#m')
    puts browser.text

Comment: It turns out that there's an error in a meta tag's attribute on that page: "Viewport argument value "device-width;" for key "width" is invalid, and has been ignored. Note that ';' is not a separator in viewport values. The list should be comma-separated. " looks like that's causing the problem.